# The LINQ expression '' could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

The issue arises while executing

```
  var q = (from i in db.Orders
                    group i by i.DateAdded.Month into grp
                    select new { Month = grp.Key, Totals = grp.Sum(i => i.TotalGross) }).ToList();
```

Which seems ok. The issue has to be related with the way `TotalGross` is declared `as calculated property` within the model

```
public class Orders
    {
        public decimal GrossA { get; set; }
        public decimal GrossB { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalGross => GrossA + GrossB;
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i fix this one?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Order
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
).TotalGross' could not be translated.
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `TotalGross` cannot be translated in to SQL.

Comment: How about if you try `grp.Sum(i => (i.GrossA + i.GrossB))` instead of `TotalGross`?

Comment: Why do you need SUM?